# How to set value to multiple mat-select in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a mat-select with multiple select option (checkbox) in angular 4

in html

```
  <mat-form-field>
     <mat-select placeholder="Location" [formControl]="toppings"  [(ngModel)]="locSelected" multiple>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of loc; let i = index" [value]="topping.value">
                    {{topping.viewValue}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
```

In ts file

```
 locSelected:Array<string>=[];
        loc= [
        { value: '1', viewValue: 'US' },
        { value: '2', viewValue: 'UK' },
        { value: '3', viewValue: 'Europe' },
        {value:'4',viewValue:'London'},
        {value:'5',viewValue:'France'},
        {value:'6',viewValue:'Italy'},
        {value:'7',viewValue:'Others'} ];
```

I'm getting the selected value from WebAPI result. I have tried using [(ngModel)], but it's not working.

From the WebApi result

```
if(result.locSelectedValue!="" && result.locSelectedValue!=null)
 {
   let location=result.locSelectedValue.split(",");
   for(var i=0;i<location.length;i++)
   {
    this.locSelected.push(loc[i]);
   } 
 }
```

The result which i will be getting from WebApi will be in format: 3,5,6

So the values Europe, France, Italy checkboxes should be selected.

How to achieve this. I am new to angular 4.

Comment: Can you show the value of `this.locSelected` after getting result from webapi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using `[formControl]` you don't need to use `ngModel`.
Once you get the record from API you can set the value to formControl and it will take care of rest.

Modified code -

```
toppings = new FormControl(); //You might have already

if(result.locSelectedValue!="" && result.locSelectedValue!=null)
 {
   let location=result.locSelectedValue.split(",");
   for(var i=0;i<location.length;i++)
   {
    this.locSelected.push(loc[i]);
   } 
  this.toppings.setValue(this.locSelected); //This will update your UI
 }
```

> Do not forget to remove `ngModel` from the `html`

Answer (score 4):

This is my answer. You can get the toppingList from web API. In here it is hard coded.

In your .html,

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your .ts,

```
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your good answer, just a small clarification you must add this line to update the user interface in the ts when retrieving data to be initialized
this.toppings.setValue(this.toppingList) ;   Add it in ngOnInit() in your example

Answer (score 0):

I think ng multiselect dropdown perfectly suits for your requirement.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown